# Javascript Password Generator - Broken Code

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined-reference, password-generator

Hey guys I have been working on a student project which is build a random password generator I have completed the code to the best of my ability doing lots of looking into youtube videos and with teachers' notes I can not seem to get it to print the end result. Any help would be appreciated. I am still new to coding so go easy :)

```js
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
// addEventListener to button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

let arrayFromLowtoHighNum = (low, high) => {
  const array = [];
  for (let i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
};

const UPPERCASE_CODES = arrayFromLowtoHighNum(65, 90);
const LOWERCASE_CODES = arrayFromLowtoHighNum(97, 122);
const NUMBER_CODES = arrayFromLowtoHighNum(48, 57);
const SYMBOLS_CODES = arrayFromLowtoHighNum(33, 47)
  .concat(arrayFromLowToHighNum(58, 64))
  .concat(arrayFromLowToHighNum(91, 96))
  .concat(arrayFromLowToHighNum(123, 126));

// Choose character length
function generatePassword() {
  var passwordLength = window.prompt("Choose a password length between 8 & 128")
  if (parseInt(passwordLength) >= 8 && parseInt(passwordLength) <= 128) {} else {
    // window alert
    window.alert("You did not enter a valid number, please try again.");
    return
  }
  // Password variables 
  var lowerCase = window.confirm("Would you like to use lower case characters?");
  var upperCase = window.confirm("Would you like to use upper case characters?");
  var numbers = window.confirm("Would you like to use numbers?");
  var specialCharacters = window.confirm("Would you like special characters?");

  // Password response
  var lowerCaseAnswer = 0;
  if (lowerCase === true) {
    lowerCaseAnswer = true
  } else {
    lowerCaseAnswer = false
  }
  var upperCaseAnswer = 0;
  if (upperCase === true) {
    upperCaseAnswer = true
  } else {
    upperCaseAnswer = false
  }
  var nummberAnswer = 0;
  if (number === true) {
    nummberAnswer = true
  } else {
    nummberAnswer = false
  }
  var specialCharactersAnswer = 0;
  if (specialCharacters === true) {
    specialCharactersAnswer = true
  } else {
    specialCharactersAnswer = false
  }
  let charCode = [];
  if (lowerCaseAnswer == true) {
    charCodes = charCode.concat(LOWERCASE_CODES);
  }
  if (upperCase == true) {
    charCodes = charCode.concat(UPPERCASE_CODES);
  }
  if (specialCharacters == true) {
    charCodes = charCode.concat(SYMBOLS_CODES);
  }
  if (nummberAnswer == true) {
    charCodes = charCode.concat(NUMBER_CODES);
  }
  const passwordCharacters = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < passwordLengt; i++) {
    const characterCode = charCode[Math.floor(Math.random() * charCode.length)];
    passwordCharacters.push(String.fromCharCode(characterCode));
    console.log(characterCode);
  }
  return passwordCharacters.join('');
}

// Parse password to #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
  passwordText.value = password;
  console.log(password);
}
```

```html
<buttun type="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives console errors

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Learn about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code. First error is a typo: `arrayFromLowToHighNum` vs. `arrayFromLowtoHighNum`.

Comment: WOW thats was a quick response thanks so much @SebastianSimon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many issues

Mostly differences between variable names and spelling mistakes

- passwordLengt  vs passwordLength
- charCode vs charCodes
- all your booleans were spelled differently when you defined them and when you used them - no need to test a boolean == true or false.
- No need for half your booleans, since they could be used directly
- reverse your test for length to save an empty function
- You can use map
- I personally use getElementById instead of querySelector for elements with an ID

This works

```js
const arrayFromLowToHighNum = (low, high) => {
  const array = [];
  for (let i = low; i <= high; i++) {
    array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
};

const UPPERCASE_CODES = arrayFromLowToHighNum(65, 90);
const LOWERCASE_CODES = arrayFromLowToHighNum(97, 122);
const NUMBER_CODES = arrayFromLowToHighNum(48, 57);
const SYMBOLS_CODES = arrayFromLowToHighNum(33, 47)
  .concat(arrayFromLowToHighNum(58, 64))
  .concat(arrayFromLowToHighNum(91, 96))
  .concat(arrayFromLowToHighNum(123, 126));

// Choose character length
function generatePassword() {
  var passwordLength = +window.prompt("Choose a password length between 8 & 128")
  if (passwordLength < 8 || passwordLength > 128) {
    window.alert("You did not enter a valid number, please try again.");
    return "";
  }
  // Password variables 
  var lowerCase = window.confirm("Would you like to use lower case characters?");
  var upperCase = window.confirm("Would you like to use upper case characters?");
  var numbers = window.confirm("Would you like to use numbers?");
  var specialCharacters = window.confirm("Would you like special characters?");


  let charCodes = [];
  if (lowerCase) {
    charCodes = charCodes.concat(LOWERCASE_CODES);
  }
  if (upperCase) {
    charCodes = charCodes.concat(UPPERCASE_CODES);
  }
  if (specialCharacters) {
    charCodes = charCodes.concat(SYMBOLS_CODES);
  }
  if (numbers) {
    charCodes = charCodes.concat(NUMBER_CODES);
  }
  if (charCodes.length === 0) {
    alert("Please choose at least one set of characters");
    return ""
  }
  const passwordCharacters = Array.from({length: passwordLength}, () => {
    const characterCode = charCodes[Math.floor(Math.random() * charCodes.length)];
    return String.fromCharCode(characterCode);
  })
  return passwordCharacters.join('');
}

// Parse password to #password input
function writePassword() {
  const password = generatePassword();
  document.getElementById("password").value = password;
}

document.getElementById("#generate").addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
<input id="password">
```

Comment: Amazing thank you, I am learning so much ! and the coding community has been really supportive!

Comment: I added a test for charCodes being empty and also added a more elegant map instead of your loop.